# Add part of filename as PDF metadata using bash script and exiftool

Tags: bash, pdf, exiftool

I have about 600 books in PDF format where the filename is in the format:

AuthorForename AuthorSurname - Title (Date).pdf

For example:

Foo Z. Bar - Writing Scripts for Idiots (2017)

Bar Foo - Fun with PDFs (2016)

The metadata is unfortunately missing for pretty much all of them so when I import them into Calibre the *Author* field is blank.

I'm trying to write a script that will take everything that appears before the '-', removes the trailing space, and then adds it as the author in the PDF metadata using exiftool.

So far I have the following:

```
    for i in "*.pdf"; 
    do exiftool -author=$(echo $i | sed 's/-.*//' | sed 's/[ \t]*$//') "$i"; 
    done
```

When trying to run it, however, the following is returned:

```
    Error: File not found - Z.
    Error: File not found - Bar
    Error: File not found - *.pdf
        0 image files updated
        3 files weren't updated due to errors
```

What about the -author= phrase is breaking here? Please could someone enlighten me?

Comment: when you seen that the shell has not expanded the `*` char, that indicates that you want to remove the dbl-quotes around `*.pdf`. Also, answer below looks very handy. An excellent first Q, please keep posting, but Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to script this.  In fact, doing so will be much slower than letting exiftool do it by itself as you would require exiftool to startup once for every file.

Try this
`exiftool -ext pdf '-author<${filename;s/\s+-.*//}' /path/to/target/directory`

Breakdown:
`-ext pdf` process only PDF files
`-author` the tag to copy to
`<` The copy from another tag option.  In this case, the filename will be treated as a pseudo-tag
`${filename;s/\s+-.*//}` Copying from the filename, but first performing a regex on it.  In this case, looking for 1 or more spaces, a dash, and the rest of the name and removing it.

Add `-r` if you want to recurse into subdirectories.  Add `-overwrite_original` to avoid making backupfiles with `_original` added to the filename.

The error with your first command was that the value you wanted to assign had spaces in it and needed to be enclosed by quotes.